# Как ускорить GET / POST запросы в Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

Нижеприведенный запрос тянет из базы список из таблицы где 1000-1500 строк (id, code, title). Но по времени это происходит не очень быстро.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно улучшить скорость запроса

DictionaryResource.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/okeds",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<Oked> getAllOkeds() {
    log.debug("REST request to get oked dictionary");
    return okedService.findAll();
}
```

okedService.java

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Oked> findAll() {
    log.debug("Request to get all oked");
    List<Oked> result = okedRepository.findAll();
    return result;
}
```

UPD.

Oked.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "oked")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Oked extends BaseType {
    private Long parentId;

    private ArrayList<Oked> okedChildren;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    public Long getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(Long parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public ArrayList<Oked>  getOkedChildren() {
        return okedChildren;
    }

    public void setOkedChildren( ArrayList<Oked> okedChildren) {
        this.okedChildren = okedChildren;
    }
}
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE oked
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  code character varying,
  name character varying,
  okedchildren bytea,
  parent_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT oked_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE oked
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Полагаю можно запустить его чуть зарание асинхронно и проблема скорости будет не так важна.

Comment: Что значит не очень быстро? не очень быстро это сколько?

Comment: Это вопрос не скорости выполнения GET/POST запроса, а вопрос скорости выборки данных из вашей БД. Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, каким образом вытаскиваются данные из базы (JDBC/ORM), какая выборка тянется и как происходит маппинг данных.

Comment: @JVic секунд 4-5

Comment: @РоманДанилов данные вытаскиваются обычным JPA методом findAll

Comment: Покажите код сущностей и DDL базы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Добавил

Comment: Попробуйте подключиться к базе с помощью psql, включите тайминг и сделайте тот же запрос. Какое время покажет?